# Voice activation button not working with kivy gui

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, speech-recognition, text-to-speech

Im trying to create a button in kivy when it's press it activates the microphone to listen to the user command.

Im unsure what exactly am i doing wrong so far.

Here is the code below

```
#Speech recognition
import speech_recognition as sr
#Text to speech
import pyttsx3
# base Class of your App inherits from the App class.
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

print('Jinx \n')


r = sr.Recognizer()
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.say(r)
engine.runAndWait()

class test(App):
        def build(self):

            return Button(text="Speak!", font_size=14)

        def say_command():
            try:
                with sr.Microphone as source:
                    voice = r.listen(source)
                    command = r.recognize_google(voice)
                    command = command.lower()
                    if 'Jinx' in command:
                        command = command.replace('Jinx', '')
                        print(command)
            except Exception:
                print('Sorry, try again.')
            return command

test().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify what you want to happen when the `Button` is pressed:

```
return Button(text="Speak!", font_size=14, on_release=self.say_command)
```

And then modify the `say_command()` method to accept the correct arguments:

```
    def say_command(self, button):
```